# Fonts displaying strange + character

Tags: css, wordpress, frontend, font-family, google-webfonts

I am working on a project, and I used the Khmer language (Khmer is a language of cambodia) on my page.

I added the language using the link from the google font, but somewhere in the text it is displaying strange + characters, what can i do to overcome this issue.

Please find the attached image, you can see below the text + characters are coming, these are not the part of language. Can someone please guide me on this?

Thanks and Regards,

Rahul

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ubol.png)

Answer (score 1):

try using [early access Google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/earlyaccess#Noto+Sans+Khmer+UI) and search for the Khmer language option.
Here is the import link for Khmer Google fonts to use in CSS file.

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosanskhmerui.css);
```

Comment: I tried applying this, but when applying this it is also giving some strange characters (dotted circles) along with + sign.

Comment: can you please share some of your code.

Comment: <style>
      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosanskhmerui.css");
      
      .khmer{
        font-family: 'Noto Sans Khmer UI', sans-serif;
      }
    </style>